# How to calculate the weights for Discrete Laplacian Operator?

Tags: co.combinatorics, laplacian, taylor-series, numerical-integration, laplace-equation

I am following [this paper](https://mathematicians.korea.ac.kr/cfdkim/wp-content/uploads/sites/15/2023/06/ISOTROPIC_FDM.pdf) step by step and want to build an isotropic Laplacian kernel. As shown in the following figure, I can understand until using Taylor to expand the 2D discrete Laplacian operator, but in step (12), the author multiplied this Laplace equation by the weights of "w" and "(1-w)", which is exactly what I don't understand. I know that the distance between the diagonal and the center is the square root of 2, so why not 1/(h ^ 2) and 1/2 (h ^ 2) as the weights? What is the difference between these two? And why does the author take 4/5 as the value of w? I would be appreciated for any explanations or resources.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTZFl.jpg)